# How do I ward off Springtrap in FNAF 3 when he is at the office door?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-3

I understand that using the audio too much can result in a Foxy jumpscare, and that you can seal off vents to prevent Springtrap from reaching you through them, but what about when he is right outside the office doorway? You can try to click on him (which does nothing) and you can look away (which results in him killing you) or you can stare at him without moving (Which also results in him killing you). This is all I can think of doing.

Am I allowed to use the audio in another room to lure him away from the doorway after he already saw me, or am I just gonna die anyways? (If there is some other way, can you please tell me?) Plus, whenever I see him on camera, and I use the audio in that same area I see him, it just makes me see a Phantom in the office with me and I have to restart the ventilation system. ***What am I doing right and what am I doing wrong?***

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything.  Once Springtrap reaches the door, if you look away he will get you.  This is why you need to use the sound queues to make Springtrap walk towards them and away from your office.

Your best bet is to stare him down as long as you can in hopes that you are close enough to 6am, otherwise, you are already dead.

As for the phantom part that's happening to you, if you see a phantom up close in the camera lens (which I believe is Ballon Boy) switch cameras and then close the camera feed (or continuing looking at other cameras).  If you close the camera feed on the screen with the phantom staring at you, he will be in the office with you and will jump at you.

Answer (score 0):

When Springtrap appears in the doorway, you need to make sure that you are able to play the Balloon Boy audio to distract Springtrap and make it look for the noise that sounds like a child, or just stare at him, never go onto the cameras or reboot or look away while he’s there, because that will cause you to get jumpscared by Springtrap, and get a game over.
I’ve actually never seen a playthrough or played fnaf 3 ( or any other fnaf game ) so sorry if this doesn’t actually help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing right is keeping Springtap away, what I normally do is keep Springtrap on cam 8, because he can't go into a vent, and I keep him there until one of the systems breaks down, which you can then quickly scroll over and reboot them and play another audio noise to get Springtrap back to cam 08.

However, when Springtrap is at your door, there is pretty much nothing that can save you, the best method I can think of however saved me on night 4 at 5AM. when Springtap is peeking his head out your door, immediately go to camera 1 and play the audio, it doesn't always work, but it's a gamble you'll have to take. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well I can say that actually if you saw him close enough to the time he got there he will allow you to go to the cameras and you can use the sound, But idk if he’ll move though I do know it’s mostly from you starring at him then going to reboot screen that kills you.

Answer (score -1):

Once he’s in the doorway, it’s already too late, you can stare him down for as long as possible, but once you look away, pull up reboots/cameras, or blink from the ventilation going out, he will kill you. You have to lure him away before he appears in the doorway. I believe you are still able to lure him away while he’s in the window, but not the door. Keep essential vents sealed off and use the BB sound queues to lead him to different rooms.